# No line break in html dd-element

Tags: html, css, image, list-definition

I am trying to get the image caption which is a dd-element to break so it is as wide as it's dt-element. I don't want to use a width and using display: inline and float: left do not work. I have code and example here: http://jsfiddle.net/PnyHs/11/. I'm using Firefox 9 to test.

The only solution I can come up with right now is to use javascript to measure the dt-element and set that width to the dd-element.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: This is more difficult that it looks. Do you need to support IE7?

Comment: Yes, IE7 support is required and you are right, it is more difficult than it looks. I have solved my problem with a little javascript as I see know other solution without changing the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the structure of your HTML and not use `max-width`, I dare to say this is impossible, and here is why:

You are expecting the `img` object to constrain the `dd` element. However both elements are siblings and can only be constrained in terms of width by their parent (alternatively an element can be stretched out by its children). Hence, the `dd` will expand as much as it wants because the parent element is not limiting it.

Of course this could be solved by setting the width of the parent element, however you've mentioned that you don't want to do that since the pictures will have different sizes.

So unfortunately unless you change your HTML structure this won't be possible without JavaScript (unless I'm missing something obvious here).

Comment: Thanks. I've given this answer the heads up because it's congruent with my thoughts and findings. I have in fact solved the issue with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dl` markup for an image and a caption is artificial and doesn’t make styling any easier. The only approach to the problem (making the caption as wide as the image) that does not need scripting or setting image width explicitly seems to be to use a single-cell table with a `caption` element, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bgzs/) and [my page on image captions](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html). Example:

```
<table class="photo">
    <caption align="bottom">Image Caption with a very very very very very long    
     text</caption>
    <tr><td>
        <img title="" alt="" src="http://dummyimage.com/120x100/82d91f/fff">
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to solve this without changing the html. Thanks for the link, I'll hang on to that for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a width to your `dl` element? The same width as your image like this http://jsfiddle.net/PnyHs/12/

Comment: The image width can vary so I don't want to use a width. I'm not sure if this is possible though. As mentioned above, my last resort is to set the width as you did in your example but with javascript dynamically.

Comment: I see. As you say, unless you know the width I don't think this is possible with just html/css unfortunately.

Comment: Just thought, how about a compromise by adding a `max-width` of say 200px?